# api response returning with "↵"

Tags: javascript, php, python, json, api

i am trying to use hackerrank api to compile code but with some languages the response contains a strange character ↵ at end.

e.g.
with C language

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()  
  { 
  // printf() displays the string inside quotation
 printf("Hello, World!");
 return 0;
}
```

responce is

```
stdout:Array(1)
0:"Hello, World!."
length:1
```

but for python

```
print("Hello, World!.")
```

response is

stdout:Array(1)
0:"Hello, World!.↵"
length:1

How can i prevent this character or atleast remove manually.

Comment: Are you looking to prevent writing the character or to remove it when reading the API result?

Comment: if i cant prevent it at least remove it

Comment: Please accept the answer below if it worked for you. This will help others who stumble across this question

Answer (score 1):

Python's print function includes a `new line` by default.

If you want direct output you should be using `sys.stdout.write`:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write('Hello, World!.')
```

Note: you may also need to call `sys.stdout.flush()`.

**Alternatively**, you can pass arguments to the `print` function in Python 3: `print('.', end='', flush=True)`.

If you are using Python 2, you can use `from __future__ import print_function` in get the Python 3 functionality mentioned above.